# Find MAX/MIN list item using LINQ?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, linq, list

I have a list Having multiple  Items and 3 props ID,DATE,COMMENT.ID field is Auto incremented in DATABASE.

Let say list Contains

```
2,16AUG,CommentMODIFIED
1,15AUG,CommentFIRST
3,18AUG,CommentLASTModified
```

I want to get a single ITEM.Item Having Minimum DATE and having Latest Comment. In this case

```
1,15AUG,CommentLASTModified
```

Any easy way to do it using LINQ.

Comment: `1,15AUG,CommentLASTModified` this row is formed from different rows in database. Is that what you want?

Comment: Basically I want a single record with Minimum dates and latest comment

Comment: `1,15AUG,CommentFIRST` - is a record with minimum date. `3,18AUG,CommentLASTModified` is a record with latest comment. You want a combination of these records

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
orderedItems = items.OrderBy(x => x.Date);

var result = items.First();
result.Comment = items.Last().Comment;
```

Answer (score 1):

To get a single item out of the list, you can order the items then take the first one, like this:

```
var result = items
    .OrderByDescending(x => x.Date)
    .First();
```

But `First` will throw an exception if the `items` collection is empty. This is a bit safer:

```
var result = items
    .OrderByDescending(x => x.Date)
    .FirstOrDefault();
```

To get the min / max of *different* columns you can do this:

```
var result = 
    new Item {
         Id = 1,
         Date = items.Min(x => x.Date),
         Comment = items.Max(x => x.Comment)
    };
```

But this will require two trips to the database. This might be a bit more efficient:

```
var result = 
    (from x in items
     group x by 1 into g
     select new Item {
         Id = 1,
         Date = g.Min(g => g.Date),
         Comment = g.Max(g => g.Comment)
     })
    .First();
```

Or in fluent syntax:

```
var result = items
    .GroupBy(x => 1)
    .Select(g => new Item {
         Id = 1,
         Date = g.Min(g => g.Date),
         Comment = g.Max(g => g.Comment)
     })
    .First();
```

Comment: `items.Min(x => x.Comment)` this will probably select the wrong comment

Comment: @IlyaIvanov You're right, it should be the "*latest*" comment, which would be `.Max(x => x.Comment)` (assuming that's actually a date as the question seems to imply)

Comment: @p.s.w.g I doubt it is. I read that as "The comment from August 18th." Your code will get the comment in highest alphabetical order, which is essentially random. Still, +1 as your answer is much more thorough.

Comment: This database design is a common anti-pattern, where they want to keep the entire comment history (instead of rewriting it) but instead of creating a new table to hold all related comments, just add new records to the system. Spend enough time as a consultant and you learn AAAAAAWLLLL the anti-patterns.